# How to move file to recycle bin in Console application?

Tags: c#

I have been able to delete files permanently with below code:

```
var DeleteFromDir = new DirectoryInfo(sFromPath);
var files = DeleteFromDir.GetFiles(".txt");
foreach(var file in files)
{
    if(bDeletePermanently)
        file.Delete();
    else
        ; //Move to recycle bin
}
```

I tried below :

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly. The needed class is found in this library.

- Add this using statement to the top of the file using
  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
- Use FileSystem.DeleteFile to delete a file, it has the option to
  specify recycle bin or not.

But this works only with UI context and my application is Console based.

Comment: You could put the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method.  It is a pretty gross violation of apartment state rules but you'll get away with it, lots of VB.NET programs do.  If your program deadlocks then you didn't.

Comment: @HansPassant, I thought it's used for threads.. didn't know we could use it for Console too.. Can you please write sample code, if it helps solving the problem I'm facing?

Comment: It certainly matters to threads.  If you create any *and* they use an apartment-threaded COM server then you'll nurse deadlock.  Rather low odds for that.  The method you are using in turns uses SHFileOperation().  A winapi function that demands STA because it *might* display a user interface.  It won't when you delete to the recycle bin so nothing to worry about there.  No idea how to turn 9 characters for [STAThread] into sample code.  Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly (there is also a NuGet package for this if you prefer), then you should be able to use the code below.

```
var DeleteFromDir = new DirectoryInfo(sFromPath);
var files = DeleteFromDir.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (bDeletePermanently)
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        FileSystem.DeleteFile(file.FullName, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
    }
}
```

> In response to your concern about the UI context, the function will only "show error dialog boxes and hide progress dialog boxes". I found this on [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.uioption?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to read further.